How to make swipe able selection control like in camera mode?
I want to make control like camera shot mode selection in standard Android smartphone (Portrait, Video, Panorama, etc, selection) using MAUI.
The buttons are swipeable and selectable by touching.
Which control can I use? Please give me short code snippet.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/carouselview/?view=net-maui-8.0

@Jason I tried CarouselView but the item size is the whole window/item. Do you have any idea how to make more than one item can be shown in the same time? Maybe simple to create ItemTemplate snippet for it?

Did you specify a size or any layout constraints?  Without seeing what you did it’s difficult to say what might be wrong.

@Jason yes, I have set the  MaximumWidthRequest="200" WidthRequest="100", I think it is enough for 3 text buttons. But it is still use the whole area.

Please [edit] your question to include additional relevant info

You may also refer to the IndicatorView which represents the number of items, and current position, in a CarouselView.
